# Of what type is this variable in my Python code, and how can I use it?

Tags: python

What is `food`? Is it a local variable? A global variable a list? Why can I use it? Is it list? Can someone please explain why the `for ... in` works that way?

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = { "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}


def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            stock[item] -= 1
            total += prices[item]
    else:
            pass
    return total
print compute_bill(food)
```

Comment: `food` is a collection of some kind.  Array, list, set, whatever.  It's something over which the code can iterate.  The `for` statement is just iterating over it.  Each time the loop runs, `item` is one of the values in that collection.  Specifically, `food` is a local variable in that function, passed to the function as a parameter.

Comment: This snippet would make more sense if the last line was `print compute_bill(shopping_list)`

Comment: Rob, please don't reference "Code Academy" in your question titles, unless you're referencing a specific tutorial there. *"Code Academy: Programming Theory"* doesn't communicate anything useful to folks scanning the question lists, though it'd make a great geek buddy cop movie title. See how I've rewritten your title here to be about this specific issue. I fixed up two of your questions, but I saw the rest, and I got exhausted.

Answer (score 5):

`food` is the argument you passed to the `compute_bill` function. But when you do:

```
print compute_bill(food)
```

It tries to find a global variable called `food`. This does not exist. I think you're looking for `shopping_list`.

Inside the `compute_bill` function, `food` is a local variable. You can not access it outside of the variable (unless you globalise it).

If you pass `shopping_list` to `compute_bill`, then `food` will be that list. Then you simply iterate through the list using the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend learning the basics of Python before asking questions about Python.

In this case, food is what is called a parameter. A parameter is sort of like a placeholder that gets passed into a function so that you can perform actions without knowing exactly what it is you are performing the action on. Let's look at an example:

> > Create a function that adds two numbers together and returns the result.
> >
> > **Problem:** you don't know the value of either number.

This is where parameters are so useful. Parameters are basically variables that you define with the function. Because of this, we can name them just like a normal variable, and put them inside the parenthesis `()` of the function.

> > We will name the first parameter **number1**
> >
> > We will name the second parameter **number2**

Let's take a look at what this looks like:

```
def add_nums(number1,number2):

    return number1 + number2
```

As you can see, we passed our two parameters inside the `add_nums` function, and returned the result of adding the two together.

Now that we have our function we can decide what the two numbers should be. Let's say `number1` equals 3 and `number2` equals 5. We can now plug these values, which are called *arguements* in to the function call:

```
add_nums(3,5)
```

Will return the sum of 3 (number1) and 5 (number2), which equals 8. As you can see, when the computer read through the code, it took the two arguments 3 and 5, and *substituted* them for `number1` and `number2` in your function. Keep in mind that the function only returns the result. If you wanted to see the result, use:

```
print add_nums(3,5)
```

And 8 will be printed to the console. As for the for loop you were asking about, it is pretty clear you need some good tutorials to read through. Here is the route I took to learn Python:

> > 1. **Read through the basics of the documentation.**
> >
> >    Nothing helps more than reading through the official syntax of Python. You'll get some great knowledge of the Python language and learn the basic format that is necessary to grasp. I started with "wetting your appetite" and read through to "4.5 pass statements". Try to understand as much as you can, but if you don't get everything don't worry - that's what the next part is for:
> > 2. **Find a good hands-on tutorial**
> >
> >    The best way to learn is by experience. But when you're just starting out, you need some help on what to do to hone your skills and really learn how it works. Codecademy is a great tutorial that teaches you everything you need to know to start writing basic to intermediate programs. You will leave Codecademy with much more knowledge you thought you would ever get, and from there the learning possibilities are endless. It does start from the basics, so step 1 above isn't necessary, but I still recommend it before jumping into Codecademy.

This is the path I took to learning Python and it helped me greatly. I still consider myself a beginner and have much to learn, but starting with these fundamentals is step 1 to becoming the best I can be. I hope you enjoy Codecademy and Python as much as I do!

**Sources:**

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

http://www.codecademy.com/